# Android Calculating values to pass to onClick method

Tags: java, android, math

I think I'm getting confused about the activity lifecycle here, I'm trying to perform a simple weights conversion, nothing spectacular.

the user enters a value, selects whether they want it  converted to lbs or kgs and when they press 'Convert' it should spit out the converted values, lookng at the stack trace it seems to have a problem with the parseInt im using.

```
public class WeightConverter extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener {
Button convertWeight;
TextView conversionResults;
EditText enterWeight;
RadioGroup weightPicker;
RadioButton radKG, radLB;
double weightValue, convertedWeight;
String weightString;
String measurement;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.weightconverter);
    initializeVariables();
}

private void initializeVariables() {
    convertWeight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvertWeight);
    conversionResults =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWeightConversion);
    enterWeight =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWeightToConvert);
    weightPicker = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgWeightType);
    radKG = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radKG);
    radLB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radLB);
    convertWeight.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ;
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btnConvertWeight:
        weightValue = Double.parseDouble(enterWeight.getText().toString());

        conversionResults.setText(weightValue + " = " + weightString + measurement);
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    switch (checkedId) {

    case R.id.radKG:
        convertedWeight = weightValue / 2.2;
        measurement = " Kilograms";
        break;
    case R.id.radLB:

        convertedWeight = weightValue * 2.2;
        measurement = " Pounds";
        break;

    }weightString = String.valueOf(convertedWeight);
}
```

}

Comment: Show us the stack trace.

Comment: logcat in eclipse shows error opening stack trace no such file?! how do i view it, is this the same as the logcat txt file? My apologies, the stack trace was showing an error previously when i coudlnt get the activity to load, I had the line ' weightValue = Integer.parseInt(enterWeight.getText().toString());' contained within initializeVariables(), I moved it and the activity loaded

Comment: A parse can fail if the string is not a valid number so it is good practice to wrap it in a try-catch block and catch any NumberFormatException. To debug this, write the string to the log or Toast it to the screen so you can see the exact data going into the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not convinced that your onCheckedChanged method is being called at all (have you seen the code entering it using the debugger?).

Try assigning it to your weightPicker radio group as below instead:

```
weightPicker.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
    {
        weightValue = Integer.parseInt(enterWeight.getText().toString());
        switch (checkedId) {

        case R.id.radKG:
            convertedWeight = weightValue / 2.2;
            measurement = " Kilograms";
            break;
        case R.id.radLB:

            convertedWeight = weightValue * 2.2;
            measurement = " Pounds";
            break;

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I hadn't set the onCheckedchangeListener, i have used the context (this) as it has worked in the past, the TextView is still returning null though

Comment: Note that you only calculate the value when the radio button changes and then only show it when you click convert. That's probably not the behaviour you're after. I suggest recording the current type (kilos or lbs) in the radio group listener (don't forget to default to one or the other to begin with) and doing the actual calculation in the convert button listener.

Comment: it works! though for some reason it wont show results straight away? I have to select the radiobuttons a couple of times and press the button a couple of times before it shows results?

Comment: how would i go about that? have a switch case in the onClicklistener? and how to default the radiobutton? use a boolean?

Comment: You could have a boolean flag (false for kilos, true for lbs) and set that to false in OnCreate and set the kilos radio button at the same time - use setChecked(true) on it. In the radio group listener, update the flag as appropriate. Then in the convert listener, use the flag to determine which calculation to do.

Comment: I have done as you suggested however when the activity is loaded and with the default radiobutton checked there is no return value :/

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If you're facing some new issues, perhaps a new question is warranted? Although if you set some breakpoints and step through using the debugger I'm sure you'll be able to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have weightValue declared as a `double` but trying to parse `integer`

```
double weightValue,
```

Instead use

```
weightValue = Double.parseDouble(enterWeight.getText().toString());
```

I would also suggest error checking on your entered value in case the user enters a non digit

Comment: Im still getting:
0.0 null returned

Comment: How are you returning 0.0 and `null`? I don't understand. And where is this being returned at? Also, did you figure out your logcat?

Comment: If it is here `weightValue = Integer.parseInt(enterWeight.getText().toString());` then either your `EditText` is `null` or has non numeric characters. I would put a breakpoint there and see what the values are. You will also want to make sure there are no spaces

Comment: Say i enter 100 into enterWeight and select Kg to convert it, conversionResults.setText returns 0.0 and the 'measurement' string returns null. I remember though that you can't just assign text to strings like that? I've also set the edittexts input to be number only

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that last sentence but it looks like you are using double in and `Strings` in your `setText()`. Convert everything to `Strings` then set it

Comment: i have updated my code to reflect how it currently looks, i have added another String variable to hold the contents of the converted weight

Comment: Please don't change your OP or it becomes useless for future members. You can update it if you are still having a similar problem or post a new question if it is a new problem. But keep the original code so it may help others.

Comment: Also, use `weightString` in your `setText()` instead of `weightValue`

Comment: sorry. its not all that different, i just added a new string variable and changed the parseint to parsedouble, the problem remains..  conversionResults.settext is returning null, passing it into a string variable didnt work either